# Is it safe to use the hash of the plain text as a key for encryption?

Tags: hash, key, unsafe, plaintext

If encrypt the  plain text with its hash is it correct??
Where Can I find a paper that speak about it?
Is it possible Known-plaintext attack?

Answer (score 0):

What would this be useful for? You would have the know the plain text to get back the plain text. If there is no need to remember the key (key is stored separately), you could as well generate a random key instead of a hash.